# create a pdf file with Jinja without creating the html file

Tags: python, jinja2, weasyprint

I'm creating a pdf file using an html template and weasyprint to convert the html file to a pdf file

The code works perfectly, but also create an html file like the pdf file

Is there a way to avoid creating the html file but only the pdf file??

this is my code

```
class Crud_db:
    def __init__(self, database = 'database.db'):
        self.database = database

    def connect(self):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(self.database)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        # print('connect seccesfully')

    def execute(self, query):
        self.query = query
        self.cursor.execute(self.query)

    def close(self): 
        self.connection.commit()
        self.connection.close()

    def save_the_last_bill_to_html_pdf(self):
        env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))
        # 3. Load the template from the Environment
        template = env.get_template('th_bill.html')

        # retrive the last general bill and details bill
        self.connect()
        query_general_bill = ''' SELECT general_bill.id, general_bill.client_name , general_bill.total , general_bill.total_margin , general_bill.number_of_products , general_bill.date_g ,general_bill.time_g , users.username user_id 
        FROM general_bill join users 
        on general_bill.user_id = users.id
        WHERE general_bill.id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM general_bill) '''
        self.cursor.execute(query_general_bill)
        result_general_bill = self.cursor.fetchall()
        

        #  retrive the detail bill 

        query_details_bill = ''' SELECT product.product_name products, details_bill.number_of_products, details_bill.prix, details_bill.margin, details_bill.date, details_bill.time 
        FROM details_bill join product
        on product.id = products
        WHERE details_bill.general_bill_id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM general_bill)'''
        self.cursor.execute(query_details_bill)
        result_detail_bill = self.cursor.fetchall() 
        # print(result_detail_bill)

        html = template.render(result_general = result_general_bill,
                            result_detail_bill = result_detail_bill)

        with open('html_report_jinja.html', 'w') as f:
            f.write(html)

        css = CSS(string='''
            @page {size: A4; margin: 1cm;} 
            th, td {border: 1px solid black;}
            ''')
        HTML('html_report_jinja.html').write_pdf('weasyprint_pdf_report.pdf', stylesheets=[css])
```

Comment: is there a way to delete it automatically I know that I can delete it, I want the one ho use this code to see only the pdf file?

Comment: Ok, that's a good idea, but how I don't know how to delete it using the code that my question a way to create a pdf file if the html file created and then deleted that's fine but how???

Comment: thank you very much @K J logically you are right, I want to know how for just knowing how doing it, this is my final project for a course,  and I want to learn how to do thing the way how I want to do it of course if it is possible

Comment: thank you for this information i will start with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a @K J idea I just add a delete functionality at the end of the function

And the code will be like this

```
def save_the_last_bill_to_html_pdf(self):
        env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('templates'))
        # 3. Load the template from the Environment
        template = env.get_template('th_bill.html')

        # retrive the last general bill and details bill
        self.connect()
        query_general_bill = ''' SELECT general_bill.id, general_bill.client_name , general_bill.total , general_bill.total_margin , general_bill.number_of_products , general_bill.date_g ,general_bill.time_g , users.username user_id 
        FROM general_bill join users 
        on general_bill.user_id = users.id
        WHERE general_bill.id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM general_bill) '''
        self.cursor.execute(query_general_bill)
        result_general_bill = self.cursor.fetchall()
        # print(result_general_bill)

        #  retrive the detail bill 

        query_details_bill = ''' SELECT product.product_name products, details_bill.number_of_products, details_bill.prix, details_bill.margin, details_bill.date, details_bill.time 
        FROM details_bill join product
        on product.id = products
        WHERE details_bill.general_bill_id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM general_bill)'''
        self.cursor.execute(query_details_bill)
        result_detail_bill = self.cursor.fetchall() 
        # print(result_detail_bill)

        html = template.render(result_general = result_general_bill,
                            result_detail_bill = result_detail_bill)

        with open('html_report_jinja.html', 'w') as f:
            f.write(html)

        css = CSS(string='''
            @page {size: A4; margin: 1cm;} 
            th, td {border: 1px solid black;}
            ''')
        HTML('html_report_jinja.html').write_pdf('weasyprint_pdf_report.pdf', stylesheets=[css])
        print('pdf file and html file created successfully')

        if os.path.exists("html_report_jinja.html"):
            os.remove("html_report_jinja.html")
            print("The file has been deleted successfully")
        else:
            print("The file does not exist!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the variable html to a file. You could also just use that variable as an input for the weasyprint HTML method. The base_url can be a path to a file or a string. In your case the string is already present in the html variable you use the write to the html file.